# Unexpected type instability in Julia function

Tags: types, julia, type-inference

I think I am getting a type instability in my code, but I'm not sure why. 
Consider the following code.

```
module test
    mutable struct Data
        arr::Array{Int64, 1}
        Data(n) = new(zeros(n))
    end

    function main()
        data = Data(5)
        data.arr
    end

    println(main())
    @code_warntype main()
end
```

The output of `@code_warntype main()` starts with the following three lines

```
Variables:
  #self#::test.#main
  data::Any
        ^^^
```

Maybe I am not interpreting the output of `@code_warntype` correctly, but it seems that I have a type-instability for the `data` variable.  Can someone shed some light on what is going on here? I'm using `0.6.2` if that helps.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my machine.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. My output starts with `Variables: #self# <optimized out> data <optimized out>`. However, the body contains references to `Array{Float64,1}` which I can clean out by using `Data(n) = new(zeros(Int64, n))`. This also reduces the length of the native code (`@code_native`). There are still references to `svec(Any, Int64)`, but you'll need someone cleverer than me to tell you what that means!

Comment: and a more Julian way to init `Data` is defining an outer constructor `Data(n::Integer) = Data(zeros(n))`.

Comment: Weird.  It was happening in some other code of mine, and I wrote up the above code just as an example (reproducing the same behaviour).  Any ideas on how I can further investigate this?

Comment: Your way may be more Julian @Gnimuc, but it doesn't remove the references to `Array{Float64,1}` in the body of the `@code_warntype` output. My way does. Just saying... ;-)

Comment: @MarkBirtwistle yeah, the correct one should be `Data(n::Integer) = Data(zeros(Int64,n))` which could avoid the implicit conversion. :)

Comment: @woggy Could you provide the entire diagnostic output of `@code_warntype` of your real code? If it is too long, you could pick some red marked lines.

Comment: Curiously, if I rewrite the original code as a 2-dimensional array (see my answer below), all the type instabilities seem to disappear! I've probably done something hideously stupid, so I await the rush of downvotes... :-(

Comment: @Gnimuc  The only red marked line is `data::Any` at the start.  The output is too long to post here and doesn't contain any reds.

Comment: One thing I notice is a lot of `SSAValue` everywhere, which does not appear in Marks 2D array answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer, but it may shed some light on the problem. If I rewrite your code as a 2-dimensional array, all the type instabilities seem to disappear and the native code is minimised:

```
module test
    mutable struct Data
        arr::Array{Int64,2}
        Data(n::Int64, m::Int64=1) = new(zeros(Int64, n, m))
    end

    function main()
        data = Data(5)
        data.arr
    end

    println(main())
    @code_warntype main()
end
```

The complete output in this case is as follows:

```
[0; 0; 0; 0; 0]
Variables:
  #self# <optimized out>
  data::test.Data

Body:
  begin 
      data::test.Data = $(Expr(:invoke, MethodInstance for test.Data(::Int64, ::Int64), :(test.Data), 5, 1)) # line 37:
      return (Core.getfield)(data::test.Data, :arr)::Array{Int64,2}
  end::Array{Int64,2}
```

All references to `Any` now seem to have miraculously disappeared from the output. I have no idea why!